# how to update prolific USB to serial driver?

Tags: windows-8.1, driver

I have a device (R31D) that read RFID card with USB port(convert serial port to USB port). When I connected it to my computer, ( windows 8.1 - drivers update - X64 ) , It does not work .
When I checked it in device manager it shows small yellow alarm on Prolific USB-to-Serial port(COM3). and when I want to connect to my device with putty. show this error : unable to open connection to COM3. Unable to open serial port.

Comment: This website is dedicated to questions about programming. All questions regarding computer hardware and drivers are off-topic. I also have to point out that your question is very broad, you do not specify what "device" you are trying to connect e.g. make and model.

Comment: Start with instruction manual for your device, then Google and then if still have a problem, a specific problem, you can try http://serverfault.com/. I suspect that you need to install drivers for your device, but since you naver said what you have and haven't tried its only a guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved the problem.
First should remove all drivers that related to prolific
second install old version of prolific (I used 2009 v).
then it works.

Answer (score 0):

I have wasted enough time on this subject I will share my final answer regarding "Please install corresponding PL2303 driver to support Windows 11 and further OS"

1. Device Manager -> Ports COM
2. Right-click "Please install corresponding PL2303 driver to support Windows 11 and further OS"
3. Update Driver -> Browse my Computer for drivers
4. Let me pick from a list...

[image]

5. You probably have old Drivers installed from ages gone by.  If not go get PL2303_Prolific_DriverInstaller_v1_12_0.zip
6. Once you have the legacy drivers, simply chose an older one.

It appears that if you "force" Windose 11 to use a specific Driver it doesn't keep throwing it away.

This solution Survived a Reboot and a Windows Update.